# What's this phrase on the wall of a toilet of a French château ?

Tags: sens, abréviations

The image below is a screenshot from *Johnny English* (2003):

[image]

On the wall I can figure out the first three words that reads *NE PAS CRACHER*, but the last word is too distorted in the view to be identified.

What is the full phrase on the wall? And what does it mean in this scenario?

Comment: "*And what does it mean in this scenario?*" -> you mean, what's the comical point of adding this phrase here?

Comment: @MercrediAndThenJedi Exactly.

Comment: There's nothing especially funny and I don't think it was added for the film. These toilets are usually just holes and it's very possible that nowadays there might be people wandering underneath, so people are asked no to spit.

Comment: ***if*** added as a comical effect, it can maybe explained by the misuse of the toilets holes as [crachoir](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crachoir). Because, when tasting wine (aussi appelé "*descente de cave*"), in order to test as many bottles as needed, you might be able to spit the wine you have in your mouth in a "*crachoir*", so that you dont' get drunk too quickly. But too many glasses might lead to confusing toilet bowl and spitting bowl (dunno if it's worth an answer though...). Having seen many Brits drunk while in Burgundy, I can find this *very* funny :))

Comment: 2/2 it's like adding a sign saying "*spitting only please*" right above a spitting bowl (=> "*please don't throw up here, use the toilets instead*"). Years and years in Burgundy, witnessing drunk people doing eveything everywhere **but** in the proper place made me laugh when seeing your picture ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's written *S.V.P.*, a standard abbreviation for *S'il vous plaît*. You will most of the time find it written as *SVP*.

Comment: So the English meaning is "don't spit if you please", right?

Comment: Please don't spit.

Comment: S'il vous plait = please, merci = thanks

Comment: It is more  "PLEASE DO NOT SPIT."  As we can see in some settlements.